# Relation between depth and lenght of a formula in First-Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm currently reading [*Mathematical Logic*](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~schwicht/lectures/logic/ws03/ml.pdf) by Helmut Schwichtenberg, and he introduces the concepts of length and depth of formulas like this [see page 3] :

**Definition.** The *depth* $dp(A)$ of a formula $A$ is the maximum length
of a branch in its construction tree.

**Defintion.** The *size* or *length* $|A|$ of a formula $A$ is the number of occurrences of logical symbols and atomic formulas (parentheses not counted) in $A$.

Further, he writes

> One can show easily that $$|A| + 1 \leq 2^{dp(A)+1}$$

I have drawn some short constructions trees and noticed that it seems to hold, though I can't really see how I would go about to prove the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove it by induction on *complexity* $k$ of the formula $A$, where $k$ is the *depth* $\text {dp}(A)$ associated to the constructiion tree of $A$.

*Base case* : $A$ *atomic*. Then $\text {dp}(A)=0$ and $|A|=1$.

We have that :

> $|A|+1=2 \le 2^{\text {dp}(A)+1}=2^1+1=2+1=3$.

*Induction step* : we have to assume that the relation holds for formulas of  complexity $k$ and prove it for a formula $A$ of complexity $k+1$.

We have to consider two cases :

*(i)* $A=\lnot B$, where $|A|=|B|+1$ and $\text {dp}(A)= \text {dp}(B) + 1$, and :

*(ii)* $A= B \lor C$, where $|A|= |B|+|C|+1$ (in "composite" formulas, we add a connective but we do not add atoms) and $\text {dp}(B \lor C) = \text {max}(\text{dp}(B), \text {dp}(C)) + 1$.

Check *(ii)* :

> $$|A|+1=(|B|+|C| +1)+1= (|B|+1) + (|C| +1) \le (2^{\text {dp}(B)+1})+(2^{\text {dp}(C)+1}) \text { (by induction hypo) } \le 2(2^{\text {max}(\text{dp}(B), \text {dp}(C))+1})=2(2^{\text {dp}(B \lor C)}) = 2^{\text {dp}(B \lor C)+1}.$$